# Writing search results only from last row in csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import json
import csv

apiKey = "MY_KEY" # Google API credentials

##perform a text search based on input, place results in text-search-results.json
print "Starting"
myfile = open("results.csv","wb")
headers = []
headers.append(['Search','Name','Address','Phone','Website','Type','Google ID','Rating','Permanently Closed'])
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerows(headers)
with open('input_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for row in filereader:
    search = ', '.join(row)
    search.replace(' ', '+')
    url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%s&key=%s" % (search,apiKey)
    urllib.urlretrieve(url1,"text-search-results.json")

    print "SEARCH", search
    print "Google Place URL", url1

    ## load text-search-results.json and get the list of place IDs
    textSearchResults = json.load(open("text-search-results.json"))
    listOfPlaceIds = []
    for item in textSearchResults["results"]:
        listOfPlaceIds.append(str(item["place_id"]))

    ## open a nested list for the results
        output = []

        ## iterate through and download a JSON for each place ID
        for ids in listOfPlaceIds:
            url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%s&key=%s" % (ids,apiKey)
            fn = ids + "-details.json"
            urllib.urlretrieve(url,fn)

            data = json.load(open(fn))
            lineToAppend = []
            lineToAppend.append(search)

            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["name"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["formatted_address"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["formatted_phone_number"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["website"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["types"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["place_id"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["rating"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')
            try:
                lineToAppend.append(str(data["result"]["permanently_closed"]))
            except KeyError:
                lineToAppend.append('')

        output.append(lineToAppend)
        wr.writerows(output)
myfile.close()
```

What this is doing is taking the search terms from one column in the input_file and running that search through the Google Places API. However, when I have multiple search terms, it only returns the last search results in the results.csv file. I am not quite sure why this is happening since it is reading all of the search terms and running them through, but only returning the last result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are only writing out the last line because you are resetting the variable `lineToAppend` within your `for` loop. However, you are not adding it to your `output` within your `for` loop. Therefore, it is getting to the end of your `for` loop and writing out the last line.

Therefore currently it looks like this: (Shortened for brevity)

```
    for ids in listOfPlaceIds:
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%s&key=%s" % (ids,apiKey)
        fn = ids + "-details.json"
        urllib.urlretrieve(url,fn)

        data = json.load(open(fn))
        lineToAppend = []
        lineToAppend.append(search)

       ...

    output.append(lineToAppend)
    wr.writerows(output)
```

Whereas it should be:

```
    for ids in listOfPlaceIds:
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=%s&key=%s" % (ids,apiKey)
        fn = ids + "-details.json"
        urllib.urlretrieve(url,fn)

        data = json.load(open(fn))
        lineToAppend = []
        lineToAppend.append(search)

       ...

        output.append(lineToAppend)
    wr.writerows(output)
```